# I need to sample n groups of n random rows from df in R

Tags: r, function, loops, random, iteration

I want to iterate n times a function that draws n rows at random from a dataframe. Since the groups consist each of 785 rows, the function is this:

```
randomSample = function(merged_df_1, n) { 
  return( merged_df_1[sample(nrow(merged_df_1), 785),] )
}
```

To iterate this function 10 times, I tried this code

```
n=10
lapply(rep(1, n), randomSample)
```

But I get the following error message

> "Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : 
>     invalid first argument"

Comment: Your code detects 1, 2, ... etc as the 1st argument of `randomSample`. Specify that separately.

Comment: Also your function does not use `n`. Is `n` supposed to be the sample size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening is that lapply takes the rep(1,n) vector and uses it as the first argument of your function. I guess you could do this:

```
randomSample = function(n, merged_df_1) { 
#note that the function doesn't really use n inside it, if you want so, you should #replace 785 for n and use rep(n,n) inside the lapply call
  return(merged_df_1[sample(nrow(merged_df_1), 785),] )
}

n=10
lapply(rep(1,n), function(x)randomSample(x,merged_df_1))
```

Comment: Or you can name the arguments with OP's original, `lapply(rep(1, n), randomSample, merged_df_1 = merged_df_1)`. (Worth noting that `merged_df_1` is a *terrible* name for the argument of a function.)